# How to pass an argument to the controller constructor? Is it the right thing to do?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I might not be doing this right because I'm new to this framework, I hope you can help ^^

As you can see in the code below, in every action I'm finding the table I want to update and then I call the method in the Table.

```
public class TableController : Controller
{
    private Lobby L;

    public TableController()
    {
        L = Lobby.Instance;

    }

    public ActionResult Index(uint id)
    {
        Table T = L.Tables[id];
        return View(T);
    }

    public ActionResult AddPlayer(byte pos, uint id)
    {
         Table T = L.Tables[id];

        ...
        T.AddPlayer(p, pos);
        ...
    }
 ...
```

}

But I've noticed that I'm doing the same thing in every method, so I though I could turn the table into an attribute so I don't need to find it for every action.

I would like to have something like this:

```
public class TableController : Controller
{
    private Lobby L;
    private  Table T;


    public TableController(uint tableId)
    {
        L = Lobby.Instance;
        T = L.Tables[tableId];
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(T);
    }

    public ActionResult AddPlayer(byte pos)
    {
        ...
        T.AddPlayer(p, pos);
        ...
    }
```

Is there anything wrong in this approach?

If this is conceptually ok, how can I pass the table ID to my constructor?
This is not working :(

```
        routes.MapRoute(
                "Table",
                "Table_{tableId}/{action}/",
                new { controller = "Table", action = "Index"}
            );
```

Comment: i would rather create BaseController that is going to be inherited by all controllers , on BaseController you can put your properties and access from any controller.. it would be more clear..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typically, a Controller constructor is used to inject dependencies, not data. Moreover, at this stage, `this.Request|Response|Session` as well as other fundamental properties are still `null`.

Try this instead:

```
protected override void Initialize(RequestContext requestContext)
{
    var tableId = Convert.ToUInt32(requestContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("tableId"));

    L = Lobby.Instance;
    T = L.Tables[tableId];

    base.Initialize(requestContext);
}
```

Comment: I suspect this is what I was looking for, let me give it a try before accepting.

Comment: Yep it does exactly what I wanted to do!

Answer (score 1):

Pass the parameter to actions not to controller.
Controller will be created each time a request happens.
You can use static properties if you need them all time.
Static properties can be accessed from any controller or action.

Comment: Good point, the lobby should definitely be static as I'm using a singleton and hence access always the same Lobby object.

Thanks!